# Javascript array search

Tags: javascript

Whats the best way to search a javascript array for an entry??
All the items will be strings.

Is it simply by using lastIndexOf? like so:

```
var list= [];
list.push("one");
list.push("two");
list.push("three");

if(list.lastIndexOf(someString) != -1)
{
    alert("This is already present in list");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Do you need all occurrences? What doesn't work about lastIndexOf?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it simply by using lastIndexOf?

Yes. However, I'd use even simpler [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if you don't need to explicitly search backwards (which you don't if you test for "does not [contain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/1048572)"). Also notice that these methods were standardized in ES5 and need to be shimmed in old browsers that do not support them natively.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran he specifically said it needs to be shimmed in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

For older browser support, you should still use a loop:

```
function inArray(arrToSearch, value) {
    for (var i=0; i < arrToSearch.length; i++) {
        if (arrToSearch[i] === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the build in array method of javascript `find`. It's the easiest way for your problem. Here is the code:

```js
var list = [], input = "two";

list.push("one");
list.push("two");
list.push("three");

function match(element){
  return element == input;
}

if(list.find(match)){
  console.log('Match found');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = ["one","two","three"];

Array.prototype.find = function(val){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === val){
            alert("found");
            return;
        }
    }
    alert("not found");
}

arr.find("two");
```

Should work in most older browsers.

https://jsfiddle.net/t73e24cp/

Comment: `Array.prototype.find` is an actual thing in future ECMAScript. I don't recommend naming the function that.

Comment: It's right around the corner (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find); Firefox and Safari already have it implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) I didn't know